# How to unset element focus between two Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm testing whether focus is being set on a DOM element under certain conditions.

I have a `describe()` containing two `it()` tests in a row. But when I position the test case where the focus *is* being set on the DOM element in the first place, then also the second test case will have the focus set on that DOM element (I'm checking for `document.activeElement`).

I've tried running `jest.resetModules()`, `jest.restoreAllMocks()`, `document.body.focus()` before and after the tests - all to no avail. Any advice on how to reset the focus?

Comment: Whilst unsetting the focus works perfectly the way described in the accepted answer, it turned out my main issue was that I didn't know I have to run some destroy commands after each `it(...)` test:

`afterEach(() => {  
        wrapper.vm.$destroy();  
        wrapper.destroy();  
    });`

That resolved some very strange issues I have observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what if you unset focus in imperative way?

```
beforeEach(() => {
 document.activeElement && document.activeElement.blur();
});
```